# How to remove extension from vendor?

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I have cloned a project written in Yii2. There are some extensions in vendor folder which I want to remove them from project. How can I do this? I am sure they are installed using composer because they are noted in composer.lock file.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to remove packages from the vendor folder you can use composer command:

```
composer remove package/name
```

If you want to remove calls to these packages in the project you need to do this manually.

Comment: I try composer remove phpunit/phpunit , but nothing is removed from vendor folder. :(

Comment: Look in `composer.json` and ensure the name is correct. If `composer remove package/name` removed the entry in your `composer.json` then run `composer update`. It should add/update/remove packages from your `vendor` directory based on the contents in your `composer.json`

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the line with the name of the package from the **composer.json** and make in command line `composer update`